# How to find spring-boot-integration-tests maven artifact

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Where is located spring-boot-integration-tests-1.5.2.RELEASE that is declared as parent for spring-boot-security-tests-1.5.2.RELEASE and could not be loaded(found) in central repository.

Comment: in other words: how to add spring boot security tests into my project to have possibility to use annotations like @WithMockUser(authorities="ADMIN")

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly add spring-security test module

If you are using gradle declare as `testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')`

If it is maven then

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Note :: version is maintained by spring boot parent pom